# ¿Cómo borrar objetos de un ArrayList con el índice?

Tags: java, arraylist

Veran tengo este codigo, el cual no tiene problema sin embargo no borra del arraylist la factura que tenga el indice a buscar. 
"facturas" es un arraylist de tipo Factura, al ejecutarlo directamente del metodo me imprime que lo hizo, pero no borra la factura. Gracias por su atencion

```java
public void pagarFactura (int indicefactura) {
    for (Factura facturab:facturas) {
        if (facturab.getindice() == indicefactura) {
            try {
                if (facturab.getValor() > fondos) {
                    System.out.println("Error, el socio no posee suficientes fondos para pagar esta factura");
                }
                else {
                    facturas.remove(indicefactura);
                    System.out.println("La factura se pagó");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("La factura fue pagada");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido Miguel, más allá de que tu pregunta esté bien o no, te recomendaría que para que tenga más alcance uses las etiquetas adecuadas, viendo el código sabemos que se trata de java, pero sería bueno que agregues es etiqueta...

Comment: ArrayList.remove borra por posición (de 0 a n-1). Si tu indice es distinto a la posición nunca va a borrar. Usa mejor por objeto que por indice.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es por editar la lista mientras la recorres. Prueba así:

```java
public void pagarFactura (int indicefactura) {
    boolean pagada = false;

    for (Factura facturab : facturas) {
        if (facturab.getindice() == indicefactura) {
            try {
                if (facturab.getValor() > fondos) {
                    System.out.println("Error, el socio no posee suficientes fondos para pagar esta factura");
                }
                else {
                    pagada = true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("La factura fue pagada");
            }
        }
    }

    if (pagada) {
        facturas.remove(indicefactura);
        System.out.println("La factura se pagó");
    }
}
```

Lo que está pasando es que te salta una excepción por editar la lista mientras la recorres, pero estás capturando la excepción (`catch (Exception e)`) y al capturarla dices que `La factura fue pagada`, pero no se borra.

Para confirmar eso, puedes ver si el resultado que obtienes dice "La factura se pagó" (que es lo que viene en el `else`) o "La factura se pagó" (que es lo que viene en el `catch`). Verás que será lo segundo.

Quizá ese try-catch habría que borrarlo o hacerlo más específico, no sé qué intentas capturar, pero ahí en cuanto tengas un error que haga saltar una excepción te dira "La factura fue pagada", y no borrará la factura.

Answer (score -2):

esto prodría funcionar:

```
// Creamos un bucle que recorre el vector.
for(int i=0;i<facturas.size();i++){
      // Si el indice se corresponde con el indice deseado se borra.
      if(facturas[i].getindice()==indicefactura){
         facturas.remove(i);
       }
   }
```

Comment: ¿podrías explicar cómo y por qué? Un código sin más no es demasiado útil. Dale a [edit] para mejorar la explicación

Comment: Con `ArrayList` no se puede acceder a elementos usando `[i]`, sería usando `.get()`. Además, estás jugando con editar el array mientras lo recorres, por lo que corres el peligro de saltarte elementos. En caso de buscar solo un elemento y borrarlo, probablemente no pase nada. Pero si hubiera varios elementos que borrar, podrías acabar saltándote alguno que hay que borrar.